# Show 32 bit and 64 bit registers in Cheat Engine

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, cheat-engine

I am currently working on a project in which I have to reverse engineer a piece of software. I need to know whether or not it is possible to show both 32 bit and 64 bit register values when looking at the memory disassembly and memory access view.

Comment: Some debuggers are more featureful than others.  All of them can at least print out a 32bit reg.  Some keep a window updated showing all registers, optionally breaking them into chunks.  Obviously in hex, it's pretty easy to do it by eye, because each byte maps to a pair of hex digits.

Comment: @PeterCordes : The problem is- if the process is a 64 bit process it only shows 64 bit register values, even if the program also uses 32 bit registers.

Comment: Like I said, most debuggers let you print whatever expressions you want.  e.g. in gdb: `print $eax` prints the low32 of rax.  Or just look at the low 32 of the registers, i.e. the last 8 hex digits.

Comment: yes, this is for cheat-engine specifically though.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  On a x64 target process, you will see 64bit registers.

But it's easy to recognize the smaller register representations.

Using the example of RAX:

- RAX is the 64bit extended version of EAX
- EAX is the 32bit **e**xtended version of AX
- AX was a 16bit register at the time when registers were 16bit

You can still easily breakdown a 64 bit register value in hexadecimal to it's smaller components.

- RAX is the total 64 bits
- EAX is the lower 32 bits
- AX is the lower 16 bits
- AH represents the **h**igh 8 bits of AX
- AL represents the **l**ow 8 bits of AX

Therefore if your 64 bit register contains:
A0B1C2D3E4F5A6B7

- EAX = E4F5A6B7
- AX = A6B7
- AH = A6
- AL = B7

You can identify this visually very easily by opening the Windows Calculator and setting it to Programmer mode, hexadecimal mode and a QWORD value.  Paste in "A0B1C2D3E4F5A6B7", then click QWORD to change it's type progressively smaller to see it's truncated values at each stage.